# Undefined variable when displaying data in view through Codeigniter Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Im trying to send data from controller to view in Codeigniter through ajax but i keep getting this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered 
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined variable: usuario
>   Filename: views/buscar_view.php
>   Line Number: 92

This is the view where i send data via Ajax to controller and  it shows too 
the information after the whole process

```php
//buscar_view:


<?php
    $diva="<div id='tabla6' align=center>";
    $divc="</div>";
    $salto_linea="<br><br>";
    echo $diva;
    echo form_label('Ingrese su Cedula:').$salto_linea;
    echo form_input(array('type'=>'text', 'name'=>'cedula','required'=>'true','id' => 'ccedula')).$salto_linea;
    echo form_submit(array('value'=>'Buscar','id' =>'enviarcedula'));
    echo form_close();
    echo $divc;
    ?>

//Ajax request

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#enviarcedula").click(function(){
                var cedula=$("#ccedula").val();
                peticionUsuario(cedula);

            });
        });

        function peticionUsuario(cedulajs)
        {
            var parametros={
                "cedula":cedulajs
            }

            $.ajax({
                data:parametros,
                type:"post",
                url:'<?php echo base_url();?>usuario_controller/recibePeticionUsuarioAjax',
                success: function(respuesta){
                    alert("Informacion  de usuario");



            }


            });

        }

//Displaying data in the view



<?php
    foreach ($usuario as $u) {


    //forma nueva
        echo   "<tr>
        <td>{$u->cedula}</td>
        <td>{$u->nombre}</td>
        <td>{$u->apellido}</td>
        <td>{$u->direccion}</td>
        <td>{$u->telefono}</td>
        </tr>" ;    
    }
    echo '</table>';
    echo '</div>';

     ?>
```

```php
//controller


<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class usuario_controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("usuario_model");
    }


    public function recibePeticionUsuarioAjax()
    {
        if($this->input->post())
        {
            $cedula=$this->input->post('cedula');
            $usuario=$this->usuario_model->buscarUsuario($cedula);
            $this->load->view("buscar_view" , compact('usuario'));  

        }

    }
}
```

```php
//model

<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


class usuario_model extends CI_Model

{

    public function buscarUsuario($cedula)
    {

          $query=$this->db->get_where('usuario',$cedula);
          return $query;
    }

}

?>
```

How can i fix this? i have tried a lot and nothing changes

Comment: ___buscar_view.php Line Number: 92___ As you `buscar.php` sample code does not have 92 lines _Can you identify line 92 for us please_

Comment: line 92 is this one :  foreach ($usuario as $u) {

Comment: there is no `usuario` variable has been declared before

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work, because in your model you don't return a query result. Use this:

```
public function buscarUsuario($cedula)
{
      $query=$this->db->get_where('usuario',$cedula);
      return ($query->num_rows()) ?$query->result():false; // returns false, if query has no results
}
```

and change in controller to these lines

```
$data['usuario']=$this->usuario_model->buscarUsuario($cedula);
$this->load->view("buscar_view" , $data);
```

and in your view something like:

```
if($usuario==false){echo 'no records found'; }
else{
  foreach ($usuario as $u) {
    //forma nueva
    // your code
  }   
}
```

Comment: check updated answer, also did you check if the query returns any rows?

Answer (score 0):

> Change this in your controller

```
 if($this->input->post())
            {
                $cedula=$this->input->post('cedula');
                $usuario=$this->usuario_model->buscarUsuario($cedula);
                $this->load->view("buscar_view" ,array ('usuario'=>$usario);

            }
```